# Log into a specific server in a Windows 2012 Remote Desktop Collection

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, high-availability, remote-desktop-services

I have 4 Windows 2012 Remote Desktop servers in 1 collection. All 4 of the servers have the RD Session Host role. I've also put the collection into High Availability Mode, so all 4 servers also have the RD Connection Broker role as well. I created a DNS A record for each of the 4 servers using the same name.

The load balancing works great. When I log into the DNS name of the collection I get which ever server is best at that moment in time.

For administration purposes, how do I log into a specific server of my choosing? I tried using just the IP address of a specific server but the connection broker takes over and potentially passes me to a different server. I want to be able to specify exactly which server I'm logging in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use /admin after the computer name in your RDP client.  Allows administrative login without consuming CAL, and bypasses connection broker.